# Why can't I display the label below the image (javafx)?

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, label

So I have a StackPane. Its height is set to 300. Inside the stackpane is an imageview containing an image and a label. I set the image height to 250 and the alignment to top-center. I set the label alignment to bottom center of the pane. and yet every time I run the code the image is pushed to the bottom of the frame and the label text is on top of it so it is difficult to read. It does not matter if the stackpane's height is 500, the image is 100 Pos.TOP-CENTER, and the label is baseline-center, the text will not be displayed under the image like it is supposed to. instead it is displayed on the bottom of the image. can someone tell me why this is happening?

```
public class VBoxProductPane extends StackPane {

    private MainController mainController;
    private String name;
    private Image image;
    private String fileName;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;
    private Button button = new Button();
    private Product product;

    public VBoxProductPane(Product product){

        setPrefSize(250, 275);
        this.name = product.getName();
        this.price = product.getPrice();
        this.quantity = product.getQuantity();
        this.fileName = product.getFileName();
        this.product = new Product(this.name, this.price, this.quantity, this.fileName);
        setImage();
        setButton();
        setLabel();
        setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
                    button.setVisible(true);
                });
        setOnMouseExited(e -> {
            button.setVisible(false);
        });
    }
    private void setButton(){
        button.setText("Explore");
        getChildren().add(button);
        button.setVisible(false);
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            button.setVisible(true);
        });
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/ProductLayout.fxml"));
                Stage secondaryStage = new Stage();
                loader.setController(new ProductPage(mainController, product));
                secondaryStage.setTitle(product.getName());
                secondaryStage.setHeight(450);
                secondaryStage.setWidth(600);

                Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
                secondaryStage.setScene(scene);
                secondaryStage.show();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
    private void setLabel(){
        Label label = new Label(getLabelText());
        setAlignment(label, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
// this does nothing
        label.setLayoutY(250);
        label.setWrapText(true);
        label.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        getChildren().add(label);
        setAlignment(label, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    }
    private String getLabelText(){
        if (this.product.getName() == null){
            System.out.println("name is null");
        }
        return this.product.getName();
    }
    private Image getImage(){
        Image image = this.product.getImage();
        return image;
    }
    private void setImage() {
        ImageView imageViews = new ImageView();
        imageViews.setImage(this.product.getImage());
        setAlignment(imageViews, Pos.TOP_CENTER);
// this does nothing
        imageViews.setFitHeight(150);
// does not matter what this height is set to
// image is always displayed at the bottom with text over top
        imageViews.setFitWidth(250);
        imageViews.setY(0);
        getChildren().add(imageViews);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ImageView` is a very simple type of `Node`.  It is **not** resizable (it doesn't have min/max/pref values).  This makes it (unfortunately) really akward to use in layouts.

The `StackPane` for example cannot make the correct decisions on what to do with the  `ImageView` (as it doesn't have a preferred size, or even a maximum size) and just assigns it as much space as possible.

Things you can do to solve this:

1) Wrap the `ImageView` in a container and set its sizes (setting the maximum sizes to be the same as the fit sizes should work).

2) Use a `VBox` or `BorderPane` so you can place the `Label` at the bottom correctly.

3) Use `setGraphic` of `Label` to integrate the `Image` directly with the `Label` control.